# План изучения Java для Web

Tags: java, java-ee

Посоветуйте план изучения java для веб, собственно, java ee. Что почитать, что необходимо знать. Понимаю, что вопрос уже задавался не один раз, но хотелось бы услышать актуальное мнение.

Немного о себе: изучал java по первому тому хорстманна, писал небольшие приложения в университете (лабораторные, курсовые работы), html, xml.
Что советуете прочитать/узнать, чтобы получить более менее полное представление о веб разработке на java.

Язык предпочтительно русский, но английский не будет большой проблемой

Comment: почитать какие требования к веб разработчикам на java, можете нагуглить вакансии на любом ресурсе

Comment: ну так требования: знания jsp, servlets, spring, hibernate и тп. Думал, вы посоветуете литературу, источники, где наиболее доступно расписаны необходимые технологии. В каком порядке и что изучать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Последовательность изучения:

1. Servlets (установить себе в конце-то концов Tomcat)
2. JSP (обратить внимание на теги и простейшие фреймворки типа Struts)
3. JDBC (перед изучением знать хотя бы что-то о SQL и не ограничиваться одним JDBC-ODBC бриджем)
4. Hibernate (попробовать пару-тройку диалектов, скажем MySQL/MS SQL Server/Oracle)
5. Spring

По JSP/Servlet есть уже классическая книга: [М.Холл: Сервлеты и Java Server Pages](http://www.piter.com/book.phtml?978531800186)

По Hibernate и Spring сложно - не знаю ничего приличного.

Answer (score 0):

Советую найти любую книжку по Java EE и сделать акцент на самые простые вещи, например; как сделать так что б дата которая посылается от клиента заходила в БД, как вытягивать из базы данных информацию - и где и как ее отображать.

А еще, если вы уже делали некие лабораторные работы то можете прямиком их же и реализовать для постройки веб-сайта, скорее всего он будет мини сайт но зато вы будете опираться на то что уже знаете .